# Distributing a simple library via clojars

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojars

I have implemented a [hyphenation algorithm](https://github.com/nikonyrh/hyphenator-clj/blob/master/src/hyphenator_clj/core.clj) (at namespace `hyphenator-clj.core`), defined it as `org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj 0.1.0` at [defproject](https://github.com/nikonyrh/hyphenator-clj/blob/master/project.clj) and pushed it to [Clojars](https://clojars.org/org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj). Uberjar seems to have files like `core__init.class`, `core.clj` and `core.class`.

However when I try to use it as a dependency on an other project I get this error:

```
$ lein uberjar
Retrieving org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator-clj/org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj/0.1.0/org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj-0.1.0.pom from clojars
Retrieving org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator-clj/org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj/0.1.0/org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj-0.1.0.jar from clojars
Compiling example.core
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator_clj__init.class or org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator_clj.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name., compiling:(core.clj:1:1)
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator_clj__init.class or org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator_clj.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name., compiling:(core.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval(Compiler.java:3657)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7474)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile1(Compiler.java:7464)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:7541)
    at clojure.lang.RT.compile(RT.java:406)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:451)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    ...
```

Must I change my project's folder structure so that it matches the expected `org/clojars/nikonyrh/hyphenator_clj__init.class`, or can I somehow override the current behavior? If there is a good tutorial about this out there I would be happy to read it.

Basically I would like to get this example project to work. project.clj:

```
(defproject example "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description ""
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj "0.1.0"]]
  :javac-options ["-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "-Xlint:-options"]
  :aot [example.core]
  :main example.core)
```

src/example/core.clj:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj :as h])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& argv] (doseq [arg argv] (println (h/hyphenate arg :hyphen \-))))
```

I'm suspecting I also have the english.txt in a wrong directory, as it isn't contained in the uberjar but resource files are an other topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahaa at least I understand the process a bit better now, basically my `require` has to match the structure of the used JAR file, which may be very different from the project's name. For example [cc.qbits/spandex](https://clojars.org/cc.qbits/spandex) is actually `require`d as `qbits.spandex`.

The english.txt dependency was fixed by moving it to `resources` folder, deploying the new version to Clojars and importing the dependency as it exists in the JAR:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [hyphenator-clj.core :as h])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& argv] (doseq [arg argv] (println (h/hyphenate arg :hyphen \-))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off not using a hyphen in the namespace `hyphenator-clj`. Why not just use `hyphenator`? But if you do I suspect that the name of the directory should have an underscore in it rather than a hyphen, so be: `hyphenator_clj`.

If fixing that issue doesn't help then another thing to look out for, which I can't see from your question, is where exactly is `core.clj` in the directory structure, and does the `project.clj` reflect that? For instance is the path for the namespace `hyphenator-clj.core` in a `src` directory off the root of your project? The root of your project being defined as where the `project.clj` is located.

Something else that would be good to see in the question is whether you can get the program to work just locally, without having packed it up into an uberjar and shipped it to clojars. My guess would be that it does work locally, but it would help for that to be stated.

Okay taking a look at your links now. You might like to read a working project deployed to clojars, that has hypens in its name, for instance [here](https://github.com/chrismurrph/default-db-format/blob/master/project.clj). The first difference you might notice is the project name you use is rather long: `org.clojars.nikonyrh.hyphenator-clj`. It should just be `hyphenator-clj`. Also I would recommend having an identifier ending in "-SNAPSHOT" as that project does.

But taking a look at the bigger picture, a great idea you suggested in the comments is to test without Clojars being in the mix at all. To do this use `lein install` on the library you want to use from another lein project.

Comment: The file is at src/hyphenator_clj/core.clj (the first link in the question is to Github). The project is hyphenator-clj as it is a port from my earlier project hyphenator-php. Well of course in Clojar's context the "clj" is just extra noise.

Comment: hyphenator-clj works "locally" in a sense that you can build it and execute the jar, but I have not tried using it on other projects besides via Clojars.